# Excel, how to adjust my formula so that my repetition starts at a certain column?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula that distribute reptitions (payments) into columns that represents months. I also have a column that states the starting month of payments. How do I adjust my formula, so that it gives me my first payment in the selected month?

Example.

A=Number of repetitions. B=Payments. C=Starting Month. D-O=January-December

If A=3. B=5000. C=4

Current formula

```
 =IF(COLUMN()-3<=$A2,$B2,"")
```

How do I get 5000 to be paid from April for 3 months, and not from January?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (not tested):

```
=IF(AND(COLUMN(D$1)-3>=$C2,COLUMN(D$1)-3<$C2+$A2),$B2,0)
```

But I think I would do it with dates like below - you can then change the formatting of cells E1-P1 to a custom format MMMM to show only the month (not tested either):

```
A                B                C               D                                                                               E                                                                   ......
Repet        Pay            Start          End                                                                          31/1/12                                                         ......
3                 5000          29/2/12     =DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2+A2+1),1)-1    =IF(AND(E$1>=$C2,E$1<=$D2),$B2,0) .....


F
=DATE(YEAR(E1),MONTH(E1+2),1)-1
=IF(AND(F$1>=$C2,F$1<=$D2),$B2,0)
```

Comment: thank you very much. The first formula does work, sort of. The only problem is, it gives more 1 more repetition that asked for. For instance, I asked for 3 repetions starting from April, it gives me 4 repetitions starting from April.